# Палец, палка и палица

Tags: этимология

Являются ли родственными слова палец, палка, палица, а также палач? Если да, то какие еще слова могут быть однокоренными к вышеназванным. Спасибо за обстоятельные ответы.
Дерзкий грумант.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

палка, палица, палач-да, родственны, палец - особняком от них.

[Палка](http://enc-dic.com/rusethy/Palka-2689.html).
Палка-древнерусское слово, образованное с помощью суффикса от исчезнувшего ПАЛА, заимствованного из тюркского, где пала – "нож". От него-палица, тяжёлая палка .

Палец-первонач. знач. "большой палец" хорошо прослеживается в стар. русск. текстах. Мошинский  связывает слав. раlъ, раlьсь "большой палец" с греч. Ψάλλω "дергаю (струны, тетиву лука)", Ψαλμός "натягивание (струн лука)" со специальным указанием на роль именно большого пальца при стрельбе из лука "по-монгольски".

Палач объясняется по-разному. Обычно толкуется как заимств. из тюрк. яз., где оно возводится к исчезнувшему палачы, суф. производному от пала «кинжал, меч» (ср. с тем же суф. басмач, казначей). Возможно, однако, и объяснение как суф. производного от пала «палка, дубина».                          
[Палач](http://etymology-dictionary.info/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0/2680/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87)

А вот само слово ПАЛА родственно слову ПАЛИТЬ, первоначально означало "то, что сжигают" и "то, что даёт огонь", В др.-русск. палъ и паль-огонь, пламя,в совр.пал - лесной пожар,диал.паль-выжженное место в лесу.Здесь праслав. корень *pol/*pel/*pal - тот же, что в словах пламя, полено, паляница,полынь(растение палит, жжёт, горчит)

Comment: Палаш, может быть, и от **pala** (меч, кинжал). Смотрим, однако, БЭС :  
>ПАЛАШ (от венг. pallos), рубящее и колющее
холодное оружие с прямым и длинным (ок.
85 см) однолезвийным (к концу
обоюдоострым) клинком. Появился в 16 в.

Палка (цитата из ответа Людмилы) :
 
>Палка-древнерусское слово, образованное с
помощью суффикса от исчезнувшего ПАЛА,
заимствованного из тюркского, где пала –
"нож". От него-палица, тяжёлая палка ...
>А вот само слово ПАЛА родственно слову
ПАЛИТЬ, первоначально означало "то, что
сжигают" и "то, что даёт огонь" 

Так я не понял, палка - исконное?? Как-то непонятно...

Comment: А что непонятно? В др.-р. было палъка-от пал/а+-ък .Вот у Фасмера:http://poliglos.info/dict.php?rus=%EF%E0%EB%EA%E0&who=fasmer
исконно русское, а вот ПАЛА-возможный тюркизм, а возможно и нет, тоже исконное. про ПАЛАШ я не говорила, говорила про ПАЛАЧ

Comment: также касательно палки интересна связь с испанским пало (дословно - палка )

Answer (score 4):

Ответ Людмилы хорош, но и я выскажу свое мнение.
Начну с простых палицы и палки. Их родство сомнению не подлежит. Два существительных, которые обозначают похожие предметы : ручное продолговатое оружие типа дубинки и  толстый прямой побег/сук (а *может, не прямой*; а может, и не деревянная палка, а железный штырь).
Возникает мысль, что корень сих вещей связан с глаголом **пасть/падать**. Палица хорошо падает на вражеские головы, а палки, бывшие смолистыми сучьями, валяются в лесу вокруг деревьев, дожидаясь, когда их сунут в костер.
**Палый** - павший (лист), издохший (зверь).
В-общем, палки падают (ими кидаются или бьются), мешалки мешают, а грелки греют, все понятно.
Теперь с пальцами разберемся. Раньше их перстами называли, потом большой толстый двусоставный боковой перст стали величать *пальцем*.
Если посмотреть на ладонь, не кажется ли он *слегка упавшим* относительно своих бравых сородичей? Большой упавший палец, даже в варежке он сидит отдельно от других.
Иногда, для практических целей, пальцы растопыривают пошире, *распяливают* их :

> В. В. Набоков. Лик (1938)
> Колдунов на него наплывал без слов и деловито пытал его на полу, раздавленного, но всегда ерзающего; **громадная, распяленная колдуновская ладонь** производила отвратительно черпающий жест, забираясь в какие-то судорожные, обезумевшие глубины.
>
> С.Н. Сергеев-Ценский. Маяк в тумане (1933)
> И, подняв левую руку, **распялил на ней пальцы** и четыре раза наклонил ее так к нему, хитро кивая в то же время подранной шапкой на уныло шагавшего мерина.

Или можно пальцами распялить... да что угодно можно распялить пальцами :

> М.Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Пошехонская старина. Житие Никанора Затрапезного, пошехонского дворянина (1887-1889) С этими словами он раскрыл рот и **распялил пальцами губы.**
>
> В. Я. Шишков. Угрюм-река. Ч. 5-8 (1913-1932) ― И ротмистр **распялил пальцами тесный ворот мундира**.

А вот живого человека и уже не пальцами :

> Я. Пропп. Исторические корни волшебной сказки (1946) «Повел их мастер в мастерскую, сейчас **одного человека на машину распялил** и стал из него жилье тянуть»

Заглянем в словарь :

> Пяличное, пялечное дело - вышивание, шитье жемчугом, золотом или шелком. *Бяста же хитре рукама пялечному делу* (15 в.) *Точие в прядивном и в пяличном деле прилежание велие имяше* (17 в.)
> СлРЯ 11-17 вв)

Подобное **пяличное шитье** без умелых девичьих или дамских пальчиков представить невозможно. Распяливать - растопыривать, растягивать, натягивать на рамку (*пяльцы*) и тп. *Пядь* - расстояние между растопыренными большим и указательным/средним пальцами. Пялить глаза - таращиться, бесцеремонно оглядывать, будто ощупывать пальчиками. *Напялить на себя что* - несуразно надеть головной убор, обувь или другие предметы одежды :

> А. С. Неверов. Ташкент -- город хлебный (1923) **Напялил пиджак** киргиз, а вагоны у поезда дернулись…

Если *казначей* и *домрачей* - тюркские заимствования,  то палач,  скорее всего, исконное словообразование, от *паличник* (страж, вооруженный палкой/палицей) < *палачник* (~мучитель, исполнитель наказания) < *палачь* (палач), ср. бородач, толмач, силач, богач, врач...

> Суффикс -ач образует существительные со значением:
>
> • лица по преобладающему признаку (силач, усач, трубач);
>
> • предмета, который служит для выполнения действия (тягач, пугач).
> [Значения суффиксов | irgali.narod.ru](http://irgali.narod.ru/files/znashenia_suffiksov.htm)

(литературные примеры - из Нацкорпуса, ему отдельное спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Палец и палка/палица (-ица- старославянский суффикс, тогда как -ка- русский) являются  этимологически однокоренными и образованы по аналогии со "старец"/"старица".